# How to remove same condition for updating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I remove the if condition which is repeating again and again?

```
 if input["custom_fields"].get("billing_notes", None):
    billing_notes.update({"value": input["custom_fields"]["billing_notes"]})

work_order_number = {
    "name": "work_order_number",
    "label": "Work Order Number",

}
if input["custom_fields"].get("work_order_number", None):
    work_order_number.update({"value": input["custom_fields"]["work_order_number"]})

contact_name_for_billing = {
    "name": "contact_name_for_billing",
    "label": "Contact Name For Billing",
}
if input["custom_fields"].get("contact_name_for_billing", None):
    contact_name_for_billing.update({"value": input["custom_fields"]["contact_name_for_billing"]})
```

Here in each dictionary the name and label keys will be always there but if the user entered the value for its related dictionary then only at that time it should be updated but in this case, the same logic is repeating again and again so how can I do this without repeating the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can perform the above action is to have a dictionary of dictionaries like so,

```py
update_dict = {
"billing_notes": {...}
"work_order_number": {...},
"contact_name_for_billing": {...}
}
```

And later, you can just loop through them and update, further considering you are using text and actual variable names at places, this could be beneficial in fact.

```py
for (key, udict) in update_dict.items():
    if input["custom_fields"].get(key, None):
        udict.update({"value": input["custom_fields"][key]})
```

In my knowledge, I do not see any other plausible simpler way to do this. Hope you find this answer useful. Do drop questions in the comments.

Comment: but the "for" loop will be like for (key, udict) in update_dict.items():

Comment: But in this case, my every dictionary becomes a string like "work_order_number", "work_order_number" and so on I'm expection the o/p like 

billing_notes: {...}
work_order_number: {...},
contact_name_for_billing: {...}

Comment: That is possible in javascript and not python. And there is no simple way to stringify a variable name - there are quite a few SO entries on that.

Comment: So if I want the expected  o/p then in this case I have to go with previous logic only?

Comment: If you have the keys as variables, then they should be equated to strings previously. I can't think of another way.